# Checkboxlist boxes won't appear checked on Update page

Tags: php, checkbox, yii2, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist on both create and update views:

```
<?php echo $form->field($model3, 'options[]')->checkboxList(['CPF' => 'CPF', 'FWL' => 'FWL', 'SDL' => 'SDL', 'CDAC' => 'CDAC']); ?>
```

Then I used this code to save the checkboxlist checked boxes as strings:

```
$model3->options = implode(',',  $model3->options);
```

Upon updating, I used this code to convert it back to an array:

```
$model3->options = explode(",", $model3->options);
```

I expect that there should be checked boxes in my update page based on what's checked upon creation. But the checkboxlist boxes remain unchecked.

Here's my controller:

```
public function actionCreateNewStaff()
{ 
  $session = Yii::$app->session;
  if($session['user_type']=='SuperAdmin'){
      $model1 = new User();
      $model2 = new UserModule();
      $model3 = new Employee();


      if($model1->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model3->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        $model1->user_type = 'BizStaff';
        $model1->status = 1;
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $model1->date_added = date('Y/m/d', time());
        $model1->avatar = UploadedFile::getInstance($model1, 'avatar');
        $model1->creator_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->_id;
        $model1->parent = $session['store_owner'];
        $model1->password = sha1($model1->password);


          if($model1->save()){
            $model2->user_id = $model1->_id; 
            $model2->save();

            $model3->user_id = $model1->_id; 
           if(isset($model3->options)){
             $model3->options = implode(',',  $model3->options);
           } 
            $model3->save();

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "Success!");
          }
          else{
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "User Registration Failed!");
          }


        return $this->redirect(['managestaff']);

      } else {              
            return $this->renderAjax('createstaff', [
              'model1' => $model1,
              'model2' => $model2,
              'model3' => $model3,
            ]);
      }
    }else{
      return $this->goHome();
  }

}

public function actionUpdateEmployee($id)
{  

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $model1 = $this->findModel($id);
    $password = $model1->password;
    $model2 = UserModule::find()->where( [ 'user_id' => new \MongoId($id) ] )->one(); 
    $model3 = Employee::find()->where( [ 'user_id' => new \MongoId($id) ] )->one();
    if(isset($model3->options)){
      $model3->options = explode(",", $model3->options);
    }  
    $username = $model1->username;

    if($model1->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model2->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model3->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

      if($model1->password != $password)
        $model1->password = sha1($model1->password);
      else
        $model1->password = $password;

      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
      $model1->date_added = date('Y/m/d', time());


        $model1->save();
        if($model1->save()){
          $model2->user_id= $model1->_id;
          $count = count($session['modules']);
          foreach($session['modules'] as $module){
            if(is_int($model2->{$module})){
                $model2->{$module} = null; //unchecked
            }
            else{  
                $model2->{$module}= '1'; //checked
            }
          } 
          $model2->save(); 
          if(isset($model3->options)){
            $model3->options = implode(',',  $model3->options);
          }  
          $model3->save();
          Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "User successfully updated!");
          return $this->redirect(['viewemployee', 'id' => (string)$model1->_id]);

      }  
    } else {
        return $this->render('updateemployee', [
            'model1' => $model1,
            'model2' => $model2,
            'model3' => $model3,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How do I display these checked boxes on my update page?

Comment: Can you show us your controller? Where the implode and explode gets called. Looks similar to my [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767947/yii2-how-to-map-a-csv-string-in-an-attribute-to-checkboxlist-in-a-form).

Comment: What is in your db after creation? Are the values stored or not?

Comment: yes they are stored. after we use `implode`, options are stored as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting my guess is that you just have to change the attribute name in the ActiveField:

```php
//from
<?php echo $form->field($model3, 'options[]')->checkboxList([....]); ?>

//to
<?php echo $form->field($model3, 'options')->checkboxList([....]); ?>
```

I hope this is correct. What you also should do is on imploding:

```php
$model3->options = empty($model3->options) ? '' : implode(',', $model3->options);
```

Since it could be that no checkbox is selected. Then an empty string will be sent to the server.